# VS2008: Is there a way to enable bracket matching for javascript?

Tags: javascript, brackets, visual-studio-2008-sp1

The bracket matching in VS2008 is a handy feature, but doesn't seem to work for javascript code.

Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: Agreed, it would be very useful, but presume it's not an option otherwise it would be enabled. But happy to be disproved!

Answer (score 0):

If VS can do this its news to me. It also has other annoyances like not allowing you to go directly to a js function (like you can with C#/VB code/CSS)

I'm currently building a web app (client side code heavy) and given up editing js in VS2008 - it just works against me.

Instead I do it all with notepad++ and the functionlist plugin. Upside is that it provides the bracket matching you're after and also splits all my functions out nicely for easier navigation, highlights the code correctly etc.

I don't see using another app as a problem as its only an alt-tab away

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm)

[Notepad++ Plugin List](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central)

I have looked for similar solutions within VS itself but they either don't work exactly how I'd like or (in one case) crash VS.